# Detecting a 500 error on the page

Tags: asp.net

I was wondering, is there a way to detect if an include file is causing a 500 error on a page? For example we use ASP and we use include files for our headers, footers and other parts of the page that occur over and over again. If one of the includes causes a 500, I want to be able to style it different than if the entire page caused a 500.

Comment: Why aren't you using Master Pages? And what kind of errors are you include files causing?

Comment: Honestly I wasn't aware of Master Pages till just now. I am fairly new to asp, so this might be something I will look into. I am not always positive what kind of errors are causing the 500s, but sometimes it contains information that is not necessarily pertinent to the main content of the page. In these cases I would like to just hide the include section or have some kind of placeholder.